# how to build Emacs from source in Docker Hub? gap between BSS and heap

Tags: emacs, docker, dockerhub

Until very recently, I've been able to build emacs from source in a docker container using [this recipe](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-docker/blob/v1.x/Dockerfile). However as of last week, all my builds have been failing with

```
Warning: Your system has a gap between BSS and the
heap (32188607 bytes).  This usually means that exec-shield
or something similar is in effect.  The dump may
fail because of this.  See the section about
exec-shield in etc/PROBLEMS for more information.
```

I've read [etc/PROBLEMS](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/etc/PROBLEMS) and it doesn't make any sense to me. Does anybody know how to interpret this for a docker container and what I can do to get emacs building again on `hub.docker.com`?

I've tried

```
cat 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/exec-shield
```

but I don't think that is really the problem, it doesn't exist in the container.

- cross-posted to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22665
- upstream bug report https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22801

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you crosspost, I crossanswer :P IMHO crossposting is bad and you should delete one of the questions.

---

This question is also being answered here (since you already found my github bug report):

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=23529

For the moment, and likely it will be this way until the emacs build system changes, the only valid solutions are:

- Don't build with a Dockerfile and build in a running container that has a seccomp profile that allows the personality syscall. For example:

  `docker run --rm -it --security-opt seccomp=unconfined emacs-builder-image`
- Disable /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space before building:

  `echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space; docker build .`

I maintain docker images at https://hub.docker.com/r/silex/emacs

Comment: cross posting is not bad when the audiences are totally different. I figured I'd get docker experts here and Emacs experts in the other forum.